# Explicit port number in HTTP Host header for AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm trying to send an HTTP request from my device to an AWS instance(with a load balancer), and it looks like it is not able to work without explicitly adding the port number (default - 443) to the Host header. I get a curt 400 BAD_REQUEST message. Per my understanding, if the port is the default, it is not required to be appended to the header. But clearly that is failing in my case. However, curl can send an identical request successfully to the same server. Upon monitoring the header, it does not have the port appended. I am not sure what might be causing this error on my device when my request is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Your understanding about the port number is correct, so the problem is somewhere else.  If you are crafting a HTTP request from scratch, it's likely that you have another unrelated error in the way you are building the request.  What kind of "device" are you sending from, and what is its environment?

Comment: Yes it is a crafted http request. What's puzzling is that appending the port number makes this error go away, so whatever "problem" existed in my request vanished. i have a hardware device with next duo tcpip stack

Comment: Very strange. Oh... what about SNI?  ALB might be balking at a SNI mismatch.  You might also check the balancer logs to see if anything helpful appears there.

Comment: So I looked at the raw request and my Host header has some additional null characters in front of it and the load balancer does not like this. Removing them fixed it for me. I'm curious why it happens only when there is a load balancer. I have another AWS instance without the load balancer, and the request goes through just fine.